# How to call nested list with uneven number of sublists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list `my_list` of 311 elements each one has up to 6 sublists. I want to get some values from the sublists of each element. I prepared a dataframe `df` with names of the 311 elements in column 1, and in column 2 there are numbers of sublists for each element:

```r
df <- summary(my_list)
df <- data.frame(df)
df <- df[1:311, c(1,3)]
df$Freq <- as.numeric(df$Freq)
```

Then I can call for the values I want to retrieve with `value1 <- my_list[[r]][[sl]][["value1"]]` making loops with `for(r in 1:nrow(df))` and `for(sl in 1:df[r, 2])`. But there must be more elegant way to do this. Can anyone help me with the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use `lapply()`

```
my_list <- list(list(list(value1=1, value2=2), list(value1=3, value2=4)),
list(list(value1=5, value2=6), list(value1=7, value2=8), list(value1=9, value2=10)),list(list(value1=11, value2=12)))

df <- data.frame(name = 1:length(my_list), num_sublists = sapply(my_list, length), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

get_value1 <- function(x) x[["value1"]]

value1_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x) unlist(lapply(x, get_value1)))

df$value1 <- unlist(value1_list)
```

Comment: Hi! There is something wrong with your solution it returns an error Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value1, value = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 3

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rrapply`:

```r
rrapply::rrapply(my_list, condition = \(x, .xname) .xname == "value1", how = "flatten")

# $value1
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $value1
# [1] 3 4
# 
# $value1
# [1] 5 6 7
```

You can also set `how = "unlist"` to unlist the output:

```r
# value11 value12 value11 value12 value11 value12 value13 
#       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
```

###### Example Data

```r
my_list <- list(
  list(data.frame(ID = letters[1:2], value1 = 1:2), data.frame(ID = letters[3:4], value1 = 3:4)),
  list(data.frame(ID = letters[5:7], value1 = 5:7))
)
```

Comment: Or with `purrr`: `my_list |> 
  purrr::flatten() |> 
  purrr::map(~ .x |> dplyr::select(value1))`

Comment: @Julian Good idea! More briefly, `my_list %>% flatten() %>% map("value1")`

Comment: Great thank you, I knew it that the selecting was unnecessary complicated!